# "nasm: error: more than one input file specified" when compiling two asm files

Tags: linux, assembly, makefile, nasm

I am trying to assemble a small beginner program in assembly language that consists of two asm files. I could make one single file but I wanted to try calling a procedure that is in an other file.
Here is my Makefile :

```
NAME        =   formatter

SRCS        =   formatter.asm clearstring.asm

OBJS        =   $(SRCS:.asm=.o)`

NASM        =   nasm
NASMFLAGS   =   -f elf64 -F dwarf

LD      =   ld

RM      =   rm -f

all:        $(NAME)

$(NAME):    $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME)

#(1):
# formatter.o:  formatter.asm
#   $(NASM) -o formatter.o formatter.asm $(NASMFLAGS)
# clearstring.o:    clearstring.asm
#   $(NASM) -o clearstring.o clearstring.asm $(NASMFLAGS)

#(2):
$(OBJS):    $(SRCS)
    $(NASM) -o $(OBJS) $(SRCS) $(NASMFLAGS)
```

When using the code under comments (1), everything works well but when I use the compact code (2), `make` gives me that :

```
nasm -o formatter.o clearstring.o formatter.asm clearstring.asm -f elf64 -F dwarf
nasm: error: more than one input file specified
nasm: error: more than one input file specified
type `nasm -h' for help
make: *** [formatter.o] Error 1
```

I understand that the assemble step isn't right but I can't make it to do :

```
nasm -o formatter.o formatter.asm -f elf64 -F dwarf
nasm -o clearstring.o clearstring.asm -f elf64 -F dwarf
```

I hope I have been clear enough for my first question in this site.
Can you please help me ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The method you have commented out as (1) is the right way to do this.  You say everything works well when you use it.  So what's the problem with using it?

Comment: The alternative is for one assembly file to `%include` another. For example, for pure assembly, I normally just have an "0index.asm" file that includes everything so I don't need to bother with make (and checking if files changed, and starting a Nasm process N number of times, and linking, and..). It's faster and easier to forget all that... :-)

Comment: @MadScientist :The method (1) is indeed working but if I have more than a handful of files to compile, it can be a bit tedious to write and to read. Brendan : thank you for that, I googled a bit your way of doing and it is interesting. I will try that

Comment: Aha!  Well that's not the question you asked.  If you'd asked "how do I avoid rewriting the same rule over and over for every source file?" then we'd have given you an answer like Michael's below, which is the right way to do it.

Comment: Brendan: that will work but it's less efficient: every time you change ANY `asm` file, you must re-assemble ALL `asm` files.  Of course assembly is fast so probably it's not too noticeable.  It might even be faster for small numbers of `asm` files.  But the larger the project the more you will feel it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule like this ought to do the trick:

```
%.o: %.asm
    $(NASM) $(NASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

`$@` and `$<` will expand to the names of the target and the (first, and in our case, only) input file, respectively.

Comment: Thank you @Michael this rule is doing exactly what I wanted! I still don't understand though why using the variables $(SRCS) and $(OBJS) doesn't work

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because that's how the `nasm` program is defined to behave: it takes a single source file as input, and it writes a single object file as output.  So when you invoke it with multiple input files and multiple output files, it fails.  This has nothing to do with `make`.  It could be that there are programs out there that take multiple inputs and outputs on one command line, and those would work.  But that's not how `nasm` works.

Comment: @MadScientist, thank you for this clear explanation. And I will try my best to formulate a perfectly unambiguous question next time ;)

Comment: Just beware of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  :-)